# Manipulating object HTMLLIElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to get the li tag from a ul element and  then hide them but when i call the hide function I get Object # has no method 'hide'

```
 var li = $(this).siblings("ul").children("li");
 li.get(0).hide ();
```

I think that the problem is that I can't call regular jquery method unless its a object if so how can I get the object and not  or if not how do I call methods form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the native element.

To hide the first element, use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead:

```
li.eq(0).hide();
```